# How can I split a file with a custom suffix?

Tags: shell, unix, split

I have a file with 100s of filenames:

```
ax
bx
cx
...
...
...
112z
```

I want to split this file into files with 10 filenames each.

```
split -a 2 -d l 10 MASTERLIST
```

TRIAL 2 works: `split -a 2 -d -l 10 MASTERLIST LIST_`

But I want the numbering of files from `01` instead of `00`. How can I do this? I know I have to use this:

```
-d, --numeric-suffixes[=FROM]  use numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic.
                                 FROM changes the start value (default 0).
```

But I am not sure how to use the `FROM` syntax.

Link: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html

Answer (score 0):

```
split -a 2 --numeric-suffixes=1 -l 10 MASTERLIST
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks! Could you please check Trial 2 in my question as well...I was in the middle of editing the question.

Comment: Also, I get this error with your solution: `split: extra operand ‘MASTERLIST’`